# Получение списка файлов в веб страницы

Tags: google-chrome

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть ссылка на сайт. С помощью google chrome devtools я могу получить ссылки на файлы(по картинке выше). Могу ли это получить как-то не используя google chrome devtools, а программно?

Answer (score 0):

Первое, что приходит в голову - Вам нужен парсер сайта :) Погуглите. Например, для поиска элементов по html-тэгу (например рисунков ), может помочь PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser и т.д. Не забываем про файлы CSS... В целом, если надо найти ссылку на файл, то логично предположить, что необходимо искать совпадение с распространенными расширениями файлов (.mp3 на Вашем скрине), и затем добавлять подстроку слева до http/https. Справа видим ?..., скорей всего это не надо. Вообщем, задачу можно решить с помощью строковых функций или уже готовых парсеров.

Comment: Это не то. Код самой страницы не содержит ссылку. Я могу извлечь адрес только с помощью google chrome devtool. Как я могу сделать это без crome?